# Should Culture change trigger page load freshly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have application in MVC where i'm doing localization for certain language.
Changing of culture is causing me to read data from Database each time.
However language change will be only for labels that too predefined text stored in resource file.
i won't see any point loading page again and calling DB each time.

can please suggest is it possible to create page without calling Database each time user change language.

Comment: Hold the data in session or in cache, then load it from there. But in my perspective, you shouldn't be worried with this problem, because how many times a user will change his culture, probably once.

Comment: How does the user change the culture? does it result in a different url?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `[OutputCache]` attribute in the controller e.g.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
public ActionResult GetPage()
{
    //Do something
    return View();
}
```

Output Cache [documentation](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc%20outputcache)